# My UI on Xoom looks ugly/Not what it looks like in eclipse

Tags: java, android, layout, user-interface, xoom

So I'm making an app for my Xoom, just starting with android development.

I've made a few buttons and all that jazz, using the ADT in eclipse to position everything (using the 10.1 WXGA Tablet config), and it looks great in the editor. As soon as I run it on my xoom however, everything is larger - even the title bar is larger, and when I try and compensate for this, by specifying lower dp and sp values in my elements, it just becomes grainy and ugly, as if it's not the correct resolution.

Am I missing a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out - I just tried adding:

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
```

to my manifest, and now it looks awesome - can anyone explain to me why though? I don't really understand the theory.

Comment: Android treated the app as "legacy", proportionally resizing - as if you would strech a small display over a larger area. It's called screen compatibility mode: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html  This is a way to support apps that were not meant or not programmed to be run on large displays (tablets). The anyDensity value is set to true by default starting with Android 1.6. The theory is explained at: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html